# How to base a Quiz/Survey on a quadrant formula

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, logic

I am trying to make a quiz with a total of 11 questions. The first 2 questions should be on the x-axis and a max score of 9. the other 9 questions should be based on the y-axis with a max score of 45.

Based on the outcome it will display a result page if you end up in either I, II, III or IV
[image]

I am so bad at mathematics and am breaking my head over this one. I've searched many plugins on the internet but none of them do what I want based on the logic that is needed.

Is there anything out there I can use to make this easier?

Comment: What does it mean to have a question on an axis? You want to display "Which planet is closest to the sun?" on the axis? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: No it's for questions about "income" on the y-axis and "liquidity" questions on the x-axis

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with questions on the y-axis or x-axis. Or do you mean you have *scores* for *answers* to questions that have an *y* component, while others have an *x* component?

Comment: Ah exactly. There's a maximum score of 9 points on the x-axis and a maximum of 45 on the y-axis. Based on that I'd like to be able to show an image if it lands in I, II, III or IV

Comment: So what is the problem? You add the scores that relate to the X coordinate to a variable `x`, and add the scores that relate to the Y coordinate to a variable `y`, and you have an x, y coordinate. Then plot. If it doesn't work for you, then share your code and show exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea where to start. I have already setup the plugin I use for the quiz/survey to give me the points of x and y axis in a hidden div. I guess I need something like if x and or y axis is > than display: I, II, III or IV. So basically I need 4 if statements to display I, II, III or IV accordingly to the outcome